# How to pass host computer working directory as a build argument to my Dockerfile using docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I would like to pass the current working directory (in this case the directory on the host computer where docker-compose.yml is located) as a build argument to my Dockerfile, so I can use that host computer directory later inside the container for some specific things.

My approach was to first define an `ARG` and `ENV` variable in the **Dockerfile** like this:

```
FROM python:3.8

WORKDIR /usr/src/runner

ARG HOST_WORKING_DIRECTORY

ENV HOST_WORKING_DIRECTORY=$HOST_WORKING_DIRECTORY
```

and then define my build argument (which I would like to be the current working directory) in the **docker-compose.yml** like this:

```
version: "3.7"
services:

  runner:
    build:
      context: "./runner"
      dockerfile: "Dockerfile"
      args:  
        HOST_WORKING_DIRECTORY: $PWD
```

However, this does not work. When I do `print(os.environ["HOST_WORKING_DIRECTORY"])` inside my running container I get empty string in response.
Any ideas how can I achieve this?

**Update:**
Interestingly I can achieve this when I build my image directly with Docker command line like this:

```
docker build --build-arg HOST_WORKING_DIRECTORY="${PWD}" -t myimage .
```

However, this does not help because I need to build my image using docker-compose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use string interpolation (`"${ENV_VAR}"`) to get the actual value of an environment variable (see [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/)).

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  runner:
    build:
      context: "./runner"
      dockerfile: "Dockerfile"
      args:
        HOST_WORKING_DIRECTORY: "${PWD}"
```

Comment: I tried using string interpolation and it still gives me an empty string in response in the container.

Comment: Just to make sure Python isn't the culprit here, can you run `docker-compose run runner /bin/sh` and then check what it prints when you run `echo $HOST_WORKING_DIRECTORY`?

Comment: Can you run `docker-compose build` to make sure the image is being rebuilt with your changes and try again?

Comment: It worked after rebuilding the image, thanks a lot!

Now it works when I run the container directly from git bash `docker-compose run runner /bin/sh`, but strangely it does not work when I use VS code Containers extension. Then I get the following warning: `WARNING: The PWD variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.`. I learned that this could mean that my environment variables are not preserved. But anyway that is different question all together.